# void * function(void * argument), how to return the function results?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am practicing for better understanding functions that return `void` pointers: `void *function_t(void *arg1, void *arg2);`

I wrote the following code. Inside the function, I take two void *arguments and cast them to `int *` for summation. After getting the sum, I will return the `void` pointer to the sum. But my code is not working. I got the following errors:

```
pointerFuncTest2.c: In function ‘main’:
pointerFuncTest2.c:23:11: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
pointerFuncTest2.c:27:5: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
pointerFuncTest2.c:28:43: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
pointerFuncTest2.c:28:5: error: too many arguments to function ‘vfunc’
pointerFuncTest2.c:22:11: note: declared here
```

The code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3   void *func_t(void *arg1, void *arg2)
  4 {
  5         int *v;
  6         *v = *(int *) arg1;
  7         int *w;
  8         *w = *(int *) arg2;
  9 
 10         int *sum;
 11         *sum = *v + * w;
 12 
 13         return (void *) sum;
 14 }
 15 
 16 
 17 
 18 
 19 
 20   int main(void)
 21   {
 22     void* vfunc(void *);
 23     vfunc = func_t;
 24 
 25     int* value1, value2;
 26     *value1 = 100;
 27     *value2 = 2;
 28     void* sumvoid = vfunc((void *)value1, (void *)value2);
 29 
 30     int *sum;
 31     *sum = *(int *) sumvoid;
 32 
 33 
 34     printf("the value of sum is now %i\n", *sum);
 35 
 36     return 0;
 37   }
```

Comment: Why did you write all those line numbers, instead of a simple comment?

Comment: It seems like you shouldn't be using pointers at all here.

Comment: because I copied the code along with the line numbers from vim.

Comment: `void* vfunc(void *);` is a function declaration, not a pointer object definition. You probably want `void *(*vfunc)(void *)`

Comment: Please don't do that; it makes it difficult for the rest of us to copy-and-paste your code and try it. Turn off line numbering before copying the code -- and add comments for any relevant line numbers.

Comment: and parameter `(void *, void*)`

Comment: @KeithThompson: The OP most probably wants: `void *(*vfunc)(void *, void *)`. See what is assigned to `vfunc`.

Comment: Hint: In `vim`, you can select all text (`ggVG`) and copy it to register `+` (`"+y`), which is the system's text copy buffer. Then you can use the usual CTRL+v in the stack-overflow edit box.

Comment: Also, if you say `int *v;`, `v` doesn't point anywhere! So `*v = ...` would cause you problem. You could simply do `int v;` and `v = ...`

Comment: thank you all guys, I now have a better understanding of void pointers. My program is now fully working. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Shahbaz: That seems to work only in `gvim`. If you're using plain `vim`, `:set nonu` turns off line numbering; you can then copy-and-paste the buffer as text (using the copy-and-paste functionality of the terminal emulator vim is running under).

Comment: @KeithThompson, I always use that from vim in terminal (in gnome). I don't know if it works in Windows or not. Also, it seems that closing vim clears that buffer. Nevertheless, your method is only limited to single-page files, because the terminal only sees one page of your file.

Comment: Another method is to use [`xclip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip), but I personally never needed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the compilation error, you need to make the function pointer signature match that of the function:

```
void* (*vfunc)(void *, void*);
vfunc = func_t;
```

You have bigger problems though. You declared pointers, but did not initialize them to point to anything. For instance:

```
int* value1, value2; // value1 and value2 are declared, but not initialized
*value1 = 100; // undefined behaviour because value1 is not initialized
*value2 = 2; // likewise
```

So you do need to make sure that your pointers are initialized. For instance:

```
int i;
int *p = &i;
*p = 42; // i == 42 at this point
```

In the case of a function that returns `void*` you will need to allocate memory dynamically. Like this:

```
int *retval = malloc(sizeof(int));
*retval = 666;
return retval;
```

Of course, `void*` is what you use when you don't know what type of object the pointer refers to. If you know what it is, then use that type.

Having said all this, your entire code is something of a travesty. You are using pointers where pointers are not needed. You are using `void*` for seemingly no good reason.

---

Responding to your comment, you seem to want to write code like this:

```
void *func_t(int i1, int i2)
{
    int *retval = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *retval = i1 + i2;
    return retval;
}
```

The caller is now responsible for calling `free()` on the returned pointer. And real code would check for errors when calling `malloc`.

I really don't know why you'd want to pass the parameters as `void*`, but suppose that's a reasonable thing to do. Your code would be:

```
void *func_t(void *i1, void *i2)
{
    int *retval = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *retval = *(int*)i1 + *(int*)i2;
    return retval;
}
```

The complete program would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *func_t(void *i1, void *i2)
{
    int *retval = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *retval = *(int*)i1 + *(int*)i2;
    return retval;
}

int main(void)
{
    void* (*vfunc)(void *, void*);
    vfunc = func_t;

    int value1 = 100;
    int value2 = 2;
    void* sumvoid = vfunc(&value1, &value2);
    int sum = *(int*)sumvoid;
    free(sumvoid);
    printf("the value of sum is now %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

It's still pretty weird mind you!

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am just trying to understand how to return a void pointer from function, and am just using the simple integer summation do demonstration this.

Comment: I guess you need to cast retval to void *. So should I use "return (void *)retval ? thank you

Comment: @TonyGW No you don't need to do that. Because this is C. Any pointer is assignment compatible with `void*`.

Comment: About `func_t` : identifiers ending with `_t` are reserved, as identifiers starting with `_`, `str` and `E`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the compilation errors do:

```
int main(void)
{
  void * (*vfunc)(void *, void *);
  vfunc = func_t;

  int * value1, * value2;
  *value1 = 100; /* This will provoke undefined behaviour as value1 is being 
                    dereferenced without having being initialised before. 
                    If then trying to write something to the where value1 is pointing
                    to, it shall point to some allocated memory. */
  *value2 = 2;   /* Same issue here as for value1. */
  void * sumvoid = vfunc(value1, value2);
```

Whether this code will do what you expect, or even run is a different story though.

Comment: thanks, I found I need to do cast: vfunc((void *)value1, (void *)value2);

Comment: @TonyGW: No, when wanting to convert any pointer to `void *` no casting is necessary in C. Please note that in your posting's code `value2` is an `int` and **not** an `int *`!

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but now I got a different kind of error when running gcc: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Compile with symbols (option `-g`) and run the code using a debugger (gdb) (or read David's answer ;-))

Comment: @TonyGW If you need to cast, then you are using a C++ compiler

Comment: @alk I think it's a shame you did not point out the problems with `*value1 = 100` in the code in your answer.....

Answer (score 1):

In the whole example, using `void*` is completely useless.

You may write

```
int *v = arg1;
```

without casting since `arg1` is a `void*`, but

```
int *v;
*v = ...
```

is wrong since `v` is not initialized.

If you eventually want to return a `void*` without allocating memory, you may declare a static int (not thread safe) :

```
static int res = ...
return &res;
```

Another error line 25 : add a `*` to `value2` :

```
int *value1, *value2;
```